# Jupyter Notebook not adaption to protocol 5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Just swtiched from a MBP to a ThinkPad, Windows 10.

Fresh download of Python 3.6. Fresh download of jupyter, pip, not conda. Tried to start kernels and the console kept looping through the below.

Cleared cache, attempted to upgrade jupyter, jupyter_client, switched browsers, all to no avail.

Any advice?

`[I 10:50:01.427 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a:187C42A5D6EE454A809E226343F1188C
[I 10:50:02.436 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a
[I 10:50:02.468 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a:187C42A5D6EE454A809E226343F1188C
[I 10:50:02.484 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a:187C42A5D6EE454A809E226343F1188C
[I 10:50:03.501 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a
[I 10:50:03.502 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 2ae61f61-fa7f-44a1-9679-2369afa9e37a:187C42A5D6EE454A809E226343F1188C`